# How to make visible notification bar (battery info, clock etc.), when I use my java me app?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, series-40, nokia-s40

I have an app (LWUIT, Java Me). When I run the app on device, it occupies the complete screen.

But I want the top panel (notification bar  of device) to be visible.
What are the solutions? Are there any settings for `lwuit`?

Comment: This is possible with `Canvas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In J2ME/LWUIT you need to find the current canvas and just call `setFullScreenMode(false)` or alternatively enable the native commands (via `Display.setCommandBehavior`).

I would recommend against this since the result would look/behave radically differently between devices.

Comment: Same as you always do in MIDP. Within the MIDlet get the MIDP Display and get the current canvas. Make sure to do it AFTER invoking show().

Comment: I tried:   javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent().setFullScreenMode(false); But class Displayable hasen't got method setFullScreenMode.

Comment: You need to downcast the Displayable to Canvas